# make dictionary only from keys then add corresponding value?

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to make a dictionary from a list items as keys, then add values to it, can add multiple values too
also I want assign variables to the values.

for example:
 `["Tim","Jim","Kim"]`

expected result: `{'Tim':[age=20], ....}`

My code

```
d={}
age=[]
for item in list:
   d=dict(zip(item,zip(age)))
print(d)
```

it gives e very weird result:  `{'k':('',), 'i:('',)...}`
Frankly speaking, do not even know, how to initiate without values, also assigning variable to values!! how can I add up corresponding values with keys? :) Help please.

Comment: Please, spend some time reading ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and ["How to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You will get better results by following the tips in those articles.

Comment: I think you forgot to add the age information. Where is it supposed to get the ages from?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Don't use `list` as a variable name because there is already a builtin `list`. Further, `age` is an empty list which might part of the problem, or might be an oversight here. We can't tell which.

Answer (score 2):

Simply this would work:

```
names = ["Tim", "Jim", "Kim"]
age = [20, 30, 40]
dictionary = dict(zip(names, age))
```

gives

```
{'Tim': 20, 'Jim': 30, 'Kim': 40}
```

Edit: If you want every value as a list, you can do this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

my_dict = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in zip(names, age):
    my_dict[k].append(v)
```

gives

```
>>> dict(my_dict)
{'Tim': [20], 'Jim': [30], 'Kim': [40]}
```

Comment: what if I want to add variable to it ``` {'Tim': [age=20], ...} ``` is it possible? so I have to make a list of values, without it I can't make a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

In your expected result **[age=20]** not a valid python data type. Please update it with correct value.

If the data type is a string you can do something like below:

```
>>> names_list = ["Tim","Jim","Kim"]
>>> d = {}
>>> for item in names_list:
    d[item] = "[age=20]"
>>> print(d)
{'Tim': '[age=20]', 'Jim': '[age=20]', 'Kim': '[age=20]'}
```

And do not use *list* as a variable as it is a builtin.

Comment: This is not an answer. Please leave this as a comment.

Comment: @M-Chen-3 I do not have enough reputation to comment :)

Comment: Okay, you improved your answer. Good job.

Comment: @PJ47 wanted to put different values, by assigning variable, age = 20 , age = 25 . like this. Not same value to all keys.

Comment: @jay.andrea please update your question with the above requirement then.